# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, html

In my JavaScript code, I keep getting the error message:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data.forEach is not a function

HTML:

```
<p class="text3"><span class="status"></span></p>
<p class="text"><span class="players"></span></p>
```

JS:

Working

```
<script>
  let url = 'https://api.rust-servers.info/players/3450';
  const playersDiv = document.querySelector('.players');
  fetch(url)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((players) => {
      console.log(players);
      generateHtml(players)
    })
  const generateHtml = (data) => {
    var html = ``;
    data.forEach(player => {
      html += `<div class="name" style="position: relative; font-size: 20px;display: block;width: 100%;"><center>${player.name}</center>`;
    })
    playersDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin', html)
  }

</script>
```

Not working

```
<script>
  let url1 = 'https://api.rust-servers.info/status/3450';
  const onlinernDiv = document.querySelector('.status');
  fetch(url1)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((status) => {
      console.log(status);
      generateHtmls(status)
    })
  const generateHtmls = (data) => {
    var html = ``;
    data.forEach(status => {
      html += `<div class="name" style="position: relative; font-size: 20px;display: block;width: 100%;"><center>${status.players}</center>`;
    })
    onlinernDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('afterBegin', html)
  }

</script>
```

The first script works, but the second one doesn't. Why am I getting the error in the second script?

Comment: What's the error? Edit... I'm stupid, generally the error should be in the body though.

Comment: @Phix There error is in the title. I don't think anyone can help you unless you tell us what `data` is. Is it an array? I bet it's not.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function

Answer (score 4):

The second part (`https://api.rust-servers.info/status/3450`) causes the issue.

The server returns:

```
{
  "name": "Sharons Server",
  "status": "Online",
  "last_seen": "1583873401",
  "players": "19",
  "players_max": "200",
  "fps": "222",
  "uptime": "3 days, 13 hrs"
}
```

Which is an object, not an array. So you cannot use `.forEach()` on it.

Comment: Thanks men! What i can use on it?

Comment: You can access the values like this: `data.name` or iterate over all keys like this: `for (const key in data) { /* do sth with the key, access the value using data[key] */ }`. Further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects

Comment: I just need to change data.forEach to data.name? I just did that and it doesn't seem to work. (I'm a beginner sorry if i ask anonying questions)

Comment: No worries. No you cannot just replace `data.forEach`. `forEach` is a function only available to arrays. You however have an object. Using `data.name` or `data.status` you are able to use the values (`"Sharons Server"`, `"Online"`). You would need to rewrite the code like this: `html += \`<div class="name" style="position: relative; font-size: 20px;display: block;width: 100%;"><center>${data.players}</center>\`;
` to recieve the same result

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this the other day debugging our frontend.
The forEach would break when an Object was returned, so we needed something else to iterate over the response.

Turns out sometimes my promise returns a Object, sometimes it returned an array.
If there was a lot of results to sort thru and the promise took longer I always got an object back.

So this works for both an array and an Object with rows.

```
if (Object.keys(players).length > 0) {
  for (const key in players) {
    html += '<div>' + players[key].status + '</div>';
  }
}
```